# Merge 3 comma delimited files into one

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to combine several comma delimited files into one and it is escaping me. I have not even begun to look at the 3rd set of files as I cannot even get the first 2 working.

### Here are the starting files:

### D:\testing\styledir\Index.Dat:

" "," ","Style1         ","Style1 Description       ","OK    ",10,10,0,120,120,0,"WH        ","WHITE  "
" "," ","Style2         ","Style2 Description       ","OK    ",0,0,0,0,0,0,"WH        ","WHITE         " 
" "," ","Style3         ","Style3 Description       ","OK    ",0,0,0,0,0,0,"WH        ","WHITE          "
" "," ","Style4         ","Style4 Description       ","OK    ",0,0,0,0,0,0,"WH        ","WHITE         "
" "," ","Style5         ","Style5 Description       ","OK    ",0,0,0,0,0,0,"WH        ","WHITE          "
" "," ","Style6         ","Style6 Description       ","OK    ",0,0,0,0,0,0,"WH        ","WHITE          "

### D:\testing\styledir* Excluding the Index.Dat

Style2:
" "," ","SA","Part1","Part1 Description",2,"","W + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part2","Part2 Description",2,"","H + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part3","Part3 Description",1,"","W-3","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part4","Part4 Description",1,"","W-3","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
Style3:
" "," ","SA","Part1","Part1 Description",2,"","W + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part2","Part2 Description",2,"","H + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part3","Part3 Description",1,"","W-3","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part4","Part4 Description",1,"","W-3","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part5","Part5 Description",1,"","H-3.75","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part6","Part6 Description",1,"","H-3.75","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part7","Part7 Description",1,"","W","L","{R}","0",0,"",3,1,""
Style5:
" "," ","SA","Part1","Part1 Description",2,"","W + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""
" "," ","SA","Part2","Part2 Description",2,"","H + .25","H","{R}","0",0,"",12,1,""

### D:\testing\styledir\colors (for testing purposes, I only have 1 file) Style2.TN

"TAN"
"Part1WH","Part1TN"
"Part2WH","Part2TN"
"Part3WH","Part3TN"

As you can see they all rely on the “Style*” to determine which ones are to be added to one line. 
Here is the expected result:

### D:\testing\styledir\output\Result.txt

Style1,Style1 Description,WHITE
Style2,Style2 Description,WHITE,SA,Part1 Description,2,,W + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style2,Style2 Description,WHITE,SA,Part1 Description,2,,W + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style2,Style2 Description,TAN,SA,Part1 Description,2,,W + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style2,Style2 Description,WHITE,SA,Part2 Description,2,,H + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style2,Style2 Description,TAN,SA,Part2 Description,2,,H + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style2,Style2 Description,WHITE,SA,Part3 Description,1,,W-3,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style2,Style2 Description,TAN,SA,Part3 Description,1,,W-3,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style2,Style2 Description,WHITE,SA,Part4 Description,1,,W-3,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part1 Description,2,,W + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part2 Description,2,,H + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part3 Description,1,,W-3,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part4 Description,1,,W-3,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part5 Description,1,,H-3.75,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part6 Description,1,,H-3.75,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style3,Style3 Description,WHITE,SA,Part7 Description,1,,W,L,{R},0,0,,3,1
Style4,Style4 Description,WHITE
Style5,Style5 Description,WHITE,SA,Part1 Description,2,,W + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style5,Style5 Description,WHITE,SA,Part2 Description,2,,H + .25,H,{R},0,0,,12,1
Style6,Style6 Description,WHITE

The files are actually rather large so I need the most efferent way to do this. 
I have tried and all my attempts end up a mess. I have looping issues where I am skipping lines and repeating lines. 
On this attempt, I am trying to write out to 2 temp files, then try and combine those. My results are not accurate. 
How can I make this work?

Here is my code as it is now:

```
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Declare files we are working with
        Dim inputFileIndex As String = "D:\Testing\StyleDir\Index.dat"
        Dim inputFileParts As String = "D:\Testing\StyleDir\"
        Dim OutFileResult As String = "D:\Testing\Output\Result.txt"
        Dim outTempFile1 As String = "D:\Testing\Output\Temp1.txt"
        Dim outTempFile2 As String = "D:\Testing\Output\Temp2.txt"

        'Declare Cleanup
        Dim fileToDelete As String

        'Delcare Readers and Writers
        Dim sw1 As StreamWriter
        Dim sw2 As StreamWriter

        'Declare Variables for File 1
        Dim linesFile1 As String()
        Dim styleLine1 As String
        Dim linetoWrite1 As String
        Dim c As Integer = 1

        'Declare Variables for File 2
        Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(inputFileParts, "*")
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim fileName2
        Dim ignoreName As String = "D:\Testing\StyleDir\Index.dat"
        Dim elementsOfFileParts As String()
        Dim linetoWrite2 As String
        Dim fileLoophold As String

        'Declare for loop
        Dim l As Integer = 1
        Dim l2 As Integer = 2
        Dim temp1Hold As String
        Dim temp2Hold As String


        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'
        'Create BackUp of Result.txt if it exists
        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'

        If System.IO.File.Exists(OutFileResult) = True Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(OutFileResult, "D:\Testing\Output\Result.bck", overwrite:=True)
        End If

        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'
        'Delete Existing Files
        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'

        fileToDelete = OutFileResult
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDelete) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDelete)
        End If

        fileToDelete = outTempFile1
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDelete) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDelete)
        End If

        fileToDelete = outTempFile2
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDelete) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDelete)
        End If

        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'
        'Read In Index.dat parse and write out temp file
        '*****************************************************************************'
        '*****************************************************************************'

        Using sr As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(inputFileIndex)

            sr.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            sr.SetDelimiters(",")

            While Not sr.EndOfData
                Try
                    linesFile1 = sr.ReadFields()

                    For Each currentfield In linesFile1

                        Select Case c
                            Case 3
                                styleLine1 = currentfield
                            Case 4
                                styleLine1 = styleLine1 & "," & currentfield
                            Case 13
                                styleLine1 = styleLine1 & "," & currentfield
                        End Select

                        linetoWrite1 = styleLine1
                        c += 1

                    Next

                    sw1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outTempFile1, True)
                    sw1.WriteLine(linetoWrite1)
                    sw1.Close()

                    c = 1

                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                      FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("line in Index.Dat = " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

            End While

        End Using



        'Get file names
        For Each fileName In fileEntries
            'Loop to get each file name
            fileName2 = fileName.Remove(0, 20)
            'MsgBox(fileName)
            'Skip Index.dat
            If fileName2.indexof(ignoreName.Remove(0, 20), 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
                'Ignore file
            Else
                'Loop to parse out double quotes and read in comma delmited file

                Using sr2 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)

                    sr2.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                    sr2.SetDelimiters(",")

                    c = 1

                    While Not sr2.EndOfData
                        Try
                            elementsOfFileParts = sr2.ReadFields()

                            For Each currentfield In elementsOfFileParts

                                Select Case c
                                    Case 3
                                        linetoWrite2 = fileName2 & "," & currentfield

                                    Case 5
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 6
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 7
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 8
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 9
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 10
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 11
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 12
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 13
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 14
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                    Case 15
                                        linetoWrite2 = linetoWrite2 & "," & currentfield
                                End Select

                                c += 1
                            Next

                            sw1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outTempFile2, True)
                            sw1.WriteLine(linetoWrite2)
                            sw1.Close()

                            c = 1
                        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                      FileIO.MalformedLineException
                            MsgBox(fileName & "Element in Parts file = " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                        End Try

                    End While
                End Using
            End If
        Next

        'Read through each line of Temp1
        Dim linesTemp1 = IO.File.ReadAllLines(outTempFile1)

        For i = 0 To linesTemp1.Length - 1
            Dim lineTemp1 = linesTemp1(i)
            Dim fields = lineTemp1.Split(","c)
            temp1Hold = linesTemp1(i).Split(",")(0)

            Dim linesTemp2 = IO.File.ReadAllLines(outTempFile2)

            For j = 0 To linesTemp1.Length - 1
                Dim lineTemp2 = linesTemp1(i)
                Dim field2 = lineTemp2.Split(","c)
                temp2Hold = linesTemp2(i).Split(",")(0)

                'Write out only lines from Temp1 that do not have match in Temp2
                If temp1Hold = temp2Hold Then

                    'Read line from temp 2 And ADD columns 2 And 3 from Index

                Else

                    sw1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(OutFileResult, True)
                    sw1.WriteLine(linesTemp1(i))
                    sw1.Close()

                End If

            Next

        Next

        Label1.Text = "Finished Writing Looping Through StyleDir"


        'Loop through to remove duplicates in file result
        Dim lines As New HashSet(Of String)()
        'Read to file
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OutFileResult)
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Loop
        End Using

        'Write to file
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(OutFileResult)
            For Each line As String In lines
                sw.WriteLine(line)
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: As a start for performance, open the new file at the top with a using statement.  You don't want to open the file repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: At the moment your code is creating the file temp1 and then reading it back into memory in its entirety, it might save a little time if you just store it in an array. There are also several ways of shortening your code. Which may or may not make a difference to execution speed. I'm working on it at the moment. Could you edit your question to include what the incorrect output is for each file, and also the expected output for the temp files please? Thanks

Comment: Just a quick question - Is your final objective simply to merge all the files with no duplication of  each style line? Cheers.